# how to conditional sequences

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sequences

I was using a trigger to auto-increment in multi-columns (conditionals) based on

```
coalesce (max(id), 1) + 1
```

it stopped working when using an external signature service that takes a couple of seconds where its concurrency started to show duplicate values.

I solved the problem primitively using sequences for a few conditional values, something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_webf_serial() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
if new.serie = 'A' then
   new.folio: = nextval ('seq_A');
elseif new.serie = 'B' then
   new.folio: = nextval ('seq_B');
  else
   new.folio: = nextval ('seq_any');
end if;
return new;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

As you can see, I require a dynamic way to associate the sequences, in this case, to new.serie; the use of elseif is limiting.

Is there a better way to use conditional sequences or to mimic by code the behavior of a sequence?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this may be an option http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/130.php

Comment: please show the structure. I really dont understand why you needed a trigger and how you use it. also using sequence is not primitive - they were designed to solve chasing condition - using sequences is advanced

Comment: @VaoTsun take any multicolumn case, sellers setting orders (Seller integer not null, Order integer not null, Orderday date not null,  ,,,); if you want orders to auto increment by seller you will need a trigger like the one in this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might create the name of the sequence depending on the name of `new.serie`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_webf_serial() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
declare
    seq_name TEXT := FORMAT('seq_%s', new.serie);
begin
   PERFORM * FROM information_schema.sequences 
       WHERE sequence_schema = 'public' AND sequence_name = seq_name;
   IF NOT FOUND THEN
       seq_name := 'seq_any';
   END IF;
   new.folio: = nextval(seq_name);
   return new;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```